# Props, emit компонентов?

Tags: vue.js

Импортирую компонент  в родителя
Как мне изменять данные с response которые я получаю в родителя
Затем кинуть их в Test - там изменять
А показать результат в родителя?
На примере counter ...

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста простой пример кода. Так же напишите какой результат вы от него получаете и какой хотите

Comment: передать значения переменной с родителя в test, и рендереть <test /> в home

Comment: добавьте код с компонентами о которых идёт речь

Comment: я просто хочу я дочернего компонента изменять данние в родителя. функция называется add(). Не получается сделать this.emit

Comment: Ну тогда всё что могу сказать - это читайте документацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите изменять данные в дочернем компоненте и видеть изменения в родительском, то вы можете, например, передавать проп не примитивным значением, а объектом и изменять его напрямую. Но куда лучше будет в вашем родительском компоненте создать переменную, которую вы свяжете дочерним компонентом посредством `v-model`, а в самом дочернем компоненте при изменении данных вызывать событие `input`.

Подробнее можете узнать о том, как работает `v-model` на странице [оф.документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-v-model-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85).

Comment: при чём здесь v-model ????

Comment: Если я не правильно понял ваш вопрос - то, пожалуйста, измените его. В нём в самом деле трудно разобраться.

Comment: Я хотел с родителя передать данные в дочерний - там их изменить , а затем итой метод изменения данных передать в родитель

Comment: Вам не нужно передавать данные вниз, а потом возвращать их вверх явно. Вы можете их связать с одной точкой при помощи `v-model`.

Comment: v-model? Реально или это прикол? v-model для полей ввода

Comment: Думаете я стал бы тратить время на то, чтобы поиздеваться над вами? Разберитесь в том, как работает `v-model`, я ведь даже ссылку приложил.

Comment: v-model для связки полей ввода а не передачи данных между компонентами) Измените, Но Вы не правы здесь