# Как во vue правильно передавать данные из дочерних компонентов в родительский через компонент

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Делаю rest-приложение на vue. В бэкэнде есть несколько связанных таблиц, например, товары склады заказы клиенты. Для каждой таблицы есть страницы - index, create, edit, show. В индексе выводится список записей таблицы. В следующих двух - форма для создания и редактирования. В шоу - тоже те же поля записи только без возможности редактирования. Сейчас каждая страница в своем файле целиком работает. Но сейчас нужно добавить еще несколько таблиц в базу и каждой сделать такие же страницы. Хочу переделать по-человечески. Сделать так: есть так же страницы для каждого действия, но для create, edit, show сделать отдельный компонент содержащий в свою очередь компоненты полей. Поля для всех трех страниц одни и те же (например для товаров - категория тип модель название артикул цена и т. д.) только в create при создании ничего передавать не надо только передать в родительский компонент страницы данные из полей, в edit нужно передать в поля данные полученные с сервера и потом обратно в родительский компонент, в шоу-страницу только предать в поля и сделать инпуты в компонентах полей не редактируемыми. То есть компонент страницы действия->компонент, содержащий компоненты полей->компонент поля с лэйблом и инпутом (несколько таких компонентов:). Промежуточный компонент одинаковый для create edit show. Как правильно передавать данные из инпутов и действие submit в компонент страницы (там уже вызывается метод с axiosом). Переходы по страница осуществляются через vue-router. При монтировании страницы данные сейчас загружаются в дата компоненты страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно отвечал на подобный вопрос, посмотрите на этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201868/414370).

В дополнение к вышеприведённому ответу могу сказать, что нужные вам методы вы можете вызывать создавая событие в дочернем компоненте используя `$emit` и отлавливая это событие в родительском компоненте.

Вызов метода по событию:

```
<ChildComponent @update="yourMethod"></ChildComponent>
```

Создание события в ChildComponent:

```
this.$emit("update")
```

Если возникнут ещё вопросы или будет что-то не понятно - буду рад помочь.

Comment: А как через компонент в данном случае передать? Метод отправки на сервер содержится в компоненте страницы, потом промежуточный компонент содержащий в себе компоненты с полями ввода. Вот надо передать из компонентов полей в компонент страницы. Можно конечно цепочку событий-эмитов. Но может быть есть какой-либо изящнее способ есть?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал такую структуру: в родительском компоненте вы создаёте места, где должны храниться изменяемые данные, а дочерние компоненты связываете с ними. У вас есть всего три варианта: `props`, `v-model` (`v-bind`, `v-on`) и `Vuex`. Какой из них больше подойдёт в вашем проекте я с уверенностью сказать не могу, но исходя из описанной в вопросе ситуации подойдёт `v-model`. Так же вы можете передавать данные через `props` объектом, в таком случае вы сможете изменять их напрямую.